# JQ:dotdotdot :: Expand parent (height) with floating child

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**Scenario:**
I have been working with a jquery script that I've found that allows me show/hide the content to with Jquery:dotdotdot for multiple nested, floated columns.

**Problem:**
Now, when expanded, the floated content is overlapping the bottom border of the **div.feature** and the **div.featureWrap** container. I have already tried to force the div element to contain floats with overflow:hidden, but...no luck.

**Desired Result:**
I would like the selected **div.feature** and the **div.featureWrap** container to expand/collapse respectively.

I'm sure it is something simple, but...I'm new to working with JS. Is it something that needs to happen with the **destroy**? I see div.css('max-height','')...

Any help would be appreciated!

See the jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/cpardon/tt5htr3s/11/

**Jquery:**

```
$(function () {
    $(".desc").dotdotdot({
        ellipsis: '...',
        after: 'a.more',
        wrap: 'word',
        fallbackToLetter: true,
        callback: dotdotdotCallback,
        watch: 'window',
        height: null
    });
    $(".desc").on('click', 'a', function () {
        if ($(this).text() == "More") {
            var div = $(this).closest('.desc');
            div.trigger('destroy').find('a.more').hide();
            div.css('max-height', '');
            $("a.less", div).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).closest('.desc').css("max-height", "60px").dotdotdot({
                after: "a.more",
                callback: dotdotdotCallback
            });
        }
    });

    function dotdotdotCallback(isTruncated, originalContent) {
        if (!isTruncated) {
            $("a", this).remove();
        }
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.left {float:left;}
.clearboth {clear:both;}
#featureWrap {width:100%;}
#featureWrap .feature {width:100px;margin:0 5px;border:1px solid #CCC;padding:7px;}
#featureWrap .feature .title {color:#777;padding:12px 0;font-size:20px;}
#featureWrap .feature .desc {font-size:12px;line-height:19px;color:#555;max-height:60px;}
#featureWrap .feature .desc a {color: rgb(224, 86, 40);text-decoration: none;}
#featureWrap .feature .desc a:hover {color: #666;text-decoration: none;}
#featureWrap .feature .desc a.less {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line 15:

```
div.css('max-height', '');
```

to

```
div.css('max-height', 'none');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tt5htr3s/16/)

Your original code will attempt to set the style inline with `''`, which in turns trying to clear the max-height, but your style of `max-height: 60px;` was set in your CSS instead. By placing a `max-height: none;`, it takes higher precedence